# Need to split old pushed commit on the branch to many

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase, git-remote, git-reset

There are 30 pushed commits on the branch. It is necessary to split the 2nd commit on the branch into 20+ commits without damaging the following commits (insert splitted commit between 1st and next 28 commits). The 2nd commit on the branch has a bunch of changes that can be placed in 20+ commits.

**Is it possible to split without damaging following commits?**

Comment: What do you mean *"damaging"*? You'll have to *rewrite* them, certainly.

Comment: Damaging = without losing the data. Need to rewrite all 28 next commits? Oh

Comment: Yes, of course, because now they'll have new parents.

Comment: Can u write instruction how to do it +- fast with git commands but without losing data?)

Answer (score 0):

ok... this will require some work on your part. The short answer is `yes`, it's possible. Long answer: It requires some work.

```
git branch second second-commit-id
# we have placed a commit on the original second revision
git checkout -b temp second-commit~
# we checkout a new branch called temp placed on the parent of second... this is where the trick starts
```

each iteration will require that you follow these steps (there will be 20, right?)

```
git checkout --detach second # we place ourselves on the target _content_ revision... detached HEAD
git reset --soft temp # set branch pointer on the previous iteration revision
# now you start checking the files and leave the content you want it to be for _this_ iteration...
# compare contents with both previous iteration (temp) and target revision (second)
# add the files when you are ready
git commit -m "A new iteration... write the proper message"
# now we need to set temp where we are
git branch -f temp # temp is now where we are
```

You will repeat that over multiple iterations until you get to a point where temp is like second

Then you can continue:

```
# replicate all changes from second up to the tip of the real branch
git cherry-pick second..master # or whatever branch you are rewriting
# if you like the result
git branch -f master # place master or whatever branch over here
git checkout master
```

And now you have your thing done.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope it will help me.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 30 pushed commits on the branch. It is necessary to split the 2nd commit on the branch into 20+ commits without damaging the following commits

```
git checkout -b newbranch thatcommit
git reset @^
```

Now you're on a new branch, your work tree contains the `thatcommit` snapshot and your index and parent are set to its parent.  Add and commit the changes each replacement commit in succession:

```
git add --patch   # or --interactive
git commit
```

or if you're lucky, the changes are self-contained in separate files, and you can just commit the individual files (see the docs for what happens when you specify a path or paths on commit).

Now you've got your replacement series for `thatcommit`. Locally set every commit with a `thatcommit` parent to have your replacement tip as parent instead:

```
thatcommit=`git rev-parse thatcommit`
newbranch=`git rev-parse newbranch`
git rev-list --ancestry-path --all --parents ^thatcommit \
| sed -n s/$thatcommit/$newbranch/p > .git/info/grafts
```

and use `git filter-branch` to bake in the rewired ancestry:

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

To back out if you don't like the results:

```
git fetch . +refs/original/*:*
```

And to clean up (either way):

```
git filter-branch -f --setup exit
rm -f .git/info/grafts
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope it will help me.

Comment: There's no immediate need for either of the last two commands, just removing things that might be annoying later.